# Is there a way to make variables over forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

I have a program that has two forms in it. Is there a way that I can make a variable in `Form1` show up in `Form2` without having to make a class or function?

I made form2 by doing:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you open one form from the other? Can you explain more about how you use those forms?

Comment: @jonathanh8686 how do you expect doing anything in code "without having to make a class or function" ? Seems to me like you're expecting some magic.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to avoid "making a class".

Comment: So your second form is modeless, so do you need the variable to be displayed in Form2 in such a way that when it is updated in Form1, it will also update in Form2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open `Form2` from `Form1`, you can do it in several ways:

- Create a constructor on `Form2` that would accept a value you want to pass.
- Create a property on `Form2` and set it before showing `Form2`.
- You may opt to pass a reference to `Form1` (via a constructor or property) and use it in `Form2` to read values of properties of `Form1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "share" a object between two forms is through their constructors (dependency injection).

e.g.

```
Form1Ctor(SharedObject obj)
Form2Ctor(SharedObject obj)

var obj = new SharedObject();
var form1 = new Form1(obj);
var form2 = new Form2(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property is only used in a single form you could make it a static

e.g.

```
public static string s { get; set; }
```